# how to create links with the newly created turtles

Tags: netlogo

I cant get some links to get created. I have been working with netlogo for some months now but i cant find the problem in this simple code

for puestos 1 ,2 and 3 the links get created but for 4 and 5 they doesnt. I cant create links using a who number because its variable.

```
 create-puestos 1[

    setxy 29.2 6.9
    set shape "silla"
    set size 1
    set color green
  ]
  create-puestos 1[

    setxy 29.2 7.45
    set shape "silla"
    set size 1
    set color green
  ]

  create-puestos 1[

    setxy 29.2 8.0
    set shape "silla"
    set size 1
    set color green
  ]

  create-entrada-puestos 1 [

    setxy 28.5 7.8
    set shape "circle"
    *create-links-with puestos with [ not any? links]*
  ]



  create-puestos 1[

    setxy 29.2 8.55
    set shape "silla"
    set size 1
    set color green
  ]
  create-puestos 1[

    setxy 29.2 9.1
    set shape "silla"
    set size 1
    set color green
  ]

  create-entrada-puestos 1 [

    setxy 28.5 8.2
    set shape "circle"
    *create-links-with puestos with [ not any? links]*
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `create-links-with puestos with [ not any? links]` with `create-links-with puestos with [ not any? my-links]`

Once any link is created, then `any? links` is `true`. `my-links` are the links belonging to a specific turtle.